# Spring Cloud AWS SQS failed to connect to service endpoint

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs

I am trying to connect and publish a message to SQS using IAM role and getting the issue that unable to retrieve requested metadata /latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document and failed to connect to service end point. What else should I do to fix the error that it failed to connect to service endpoint?

```
        SQSConfig.java
        ====================
        
        @Autowired
        private AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider;
        
        @Bean
        public QueueMessagingTemplate queueMessagingTemplate(){ return new QueueMessagingTemplate(amazonSQSAsync());}
        
        @Primary
        @Bean
        public AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync(){
               return AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder.stamdard().withRegion(Regions.US_East_1)
                                          .withCredentials(awsCredentialsProviderGet())
                                          .build();}
        
        @Primary
        @Bean
        public AWSCredentialProvider awsCredentialsProviderGet(){AWSSecurityTokenService 
               stsClient=AWSSecurityTokenServiceAsyncClientBuilder.standard()
                          .withCredentials(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance()) 
                          .withRegion("us-east-1")
                          .build();
            
            AssumeRoleRequest asssumeRoleRequest = new 
                       AssumeRoleRequest().withDurationSeconds(3600).withRoleArn("rolename")
                            .withRoleSessionName("sqs-session");
            
            AssumeRoleRequest asssumeRoleRequest = stsClient.assumeRole(asssumeRoleRequest);
            
            Credentials creds = asssumeRoleRequest.getCredentials();
            
            awsCredentialsProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider
(new BasicSSessionCredentials(creds.getAccessKeyId,creds.getSecretAccessKey(),creds.getSessionToken()));
            
            }
```

I have the following dependencies in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sqs</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.169</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sts</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.172</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: What you should do is to use AWS SDK for Java V2. You can easily use the V2 API within a Spring BOOT application.

Comment: `spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging` is up to version `2.2.6` now: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging. I would start by upgrading that, and you could remove the AWS dependencies to let spring simply pull in what ever version of AWS it needs. However the error itself sounds like a network issue, not a code issue. Does the server where this is running have access to SQS via the Internet, or via a VPC endpoint?

Comment: @MarkB: The app is being deployed in EC2 instance and it also says unable to retrieve the requested metadata /latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document